# Installing Ubuntu on an Acer laptop with a completely broken keyboard

Tags: usb, live-usb, usb-drive, acer, usb-installation

I have an Acer Aspire V3 with a completely broken keyboard running Windows 10.
The power button does work, (that's how I can power the machine), but all other
keys (including F2/F12) are all toast.

I have a bootable Ubuntu USB. How can I boot into it? I also have an external USB Keyboard.

I've tried F12 on the USB Keyboard while starting it up but that is unrecognized by the Acer. I could maybe find a way to boot into the boot selection menu through Windows but I
don't know if the USB Keyboard will work there.

Thanks

Comment: In my experience, booting into BIOS from Windows *can* allow certain connected devices to be recognized by the BIOS, even if they otherwise wouldn't be. Connect the external keyboard in Windows and be sure it's recognized, [reboot into BIOS from Windows](https://www.laptopmag.com/uk/articles/access-bios-windows-10), and see if you can get to the boot menu.

Comment: also, if your battery is completely broken that can make the keyboard not work sometimes (idk why, but that's how it is). If you remove the battery altogether and just plug in the laptop, the keyboard works again. Not sure if your battery is an issue here, but that may be a solution.

Comment: Woah, that actually works! I can use the USB keyboard inside the UEFI menu. Should I change the boot order so it looks for USBs before booting into Windows?

Comment: If you want to boot from a live USB, then that's the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hopefully this laptop can be put to use again.

Comment: @Mohammed Baig - what worked? Was it the booting into Windows, or removing the battery?  If you're comfortable opening up your laptop, it's worth having a look at the ribbon cable connnecting the keyboard to the mobo ... it might be as simple as needing a bit of a push back into its socket to get the intrinsic kb working again.

Comment: @Will, I was able to boot into the UEFI menu through Windows with the tutorial that Esther posted above. From there the external USB keyboard was working so I used that to set the boot disk priority to look for USBs before Windows Boot Manager. This laptop doesn't even have a removable battery and I'm not sure I can open this device and put it back together :P